# Continuity of a Map on a Quotient

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am trying to understand the continuity of a map on a quotient from Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* (Second Edition, page no. 72). It starts as follows.

[image]

**My Question**

What does it mean that $f:S \to Y$ is constant on each equivalence class? In other words, the definition of $f$ is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the phrase "$f$ is constant on each equivalence class," the author means that whenever $x \sim y$ one has $f(x) = f(y)$.